# Examples that show that covergen in the measure does not imply convergence almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am trying to collect a list of counterexamples about the different modes of convergence in measure theory.

By definition,

The sequence of functions ${f_n}$ converges in the measure to the function $f$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} ||f_n (x)-f(x)||=0$.

The sequence ${f_n}$ converges almost uniformly to the function $f$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists a measurable set E such that $\mu (E)\leq \epsilon $ and $ f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f$ in the complement of E.

It can be shown that the latter implies the former, but can someone provide some examples  that would show that the converse is not generally try?

Comment: $\chi_{[0,1]}$, $\chi_{[0,1/2]}$,$\chi_{[1/2,1]}$,$\chi_{[0,1/4]}$, $\chi_{[1/4,1/2]}$, $\ldots$.

Comment: What about the "marching functions" example, are you familiar with that?  See @DavidMitra example, those are the marchers.

Comment: Are you sure the latter implies the former?  What about $n\cdot\chi_{(0,1/n)}$?

Comment: If your measure space is finite, there can be no counterexample,  due to Egoroff's theorem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem). BTW: It seems that what you write as "convergence in measure" is convergence (almost) everywhere.

Comment: Defintion of convergence in measure is wrong. What do you mean by $\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|$? Is it a norm? Which one?